# http://localhost/ not working

Tags: networking, apache2, php, lamp

I've just done a fresh install of Ubuntu (10.04.1) plus LAMP (via `sudo tasksel install lamp-server`) and everything is working fine. However, it does so until I need to work on localhost when I do not have an internet connection. For example, as soon as I unplug the ethernet cable from the NIC, localhost and 127.0.0.1 stop working.

The message I get from the browser is:

> This web page is not available.

Then, as soon as I plug the ethernet cable into the laptop again, everything is back to normal again. I need to work on localhost sometimes when I do not have access to the internet.

Any idea how to fix this problem? I had this problem before, but can't remember what I did to resolve it.

Comment: Did [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/2983/22949) (which you accepted) really solve your problem? I'm asking because you said that `http://127.0.0.1` didn't work either. Whether or not `localhost` is properly mapped to `127.0.0.1` shouldn't affect whether or not `http://127.0.0.1` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check that you have this line in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

If it is not there, add it.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using firefox, Uncheck

File > Work Offline and then try again.

Comment: I'm using Chromium 5.0 and don't have firefox installed.

Comment: may be chrome issue. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42058

Comment: Certainly try `wget localhost` (or `links localhost`) to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't like localhost. Try http://0.0.0.0/

Comment: localhost works fine on my chromium (admittedly version 7, not 5 as the questioner is using)

Comment: -1: http://localhost is just as valid as any other url, if you believe there is a bug on chrome you should elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** The newest versions of Google Chrome have fixed this issue. It should be working now.

It sounds like you're using Google Chrome or Chromium - This is a bug in Chrome that I've been meaning to report (but never got around to it).  Google Chrome attempts to automatically detect a "Working Offline" status and will not allow the user to easily change it

Unfortunately with Chrome right now, you *must* be connected to some form of network to use localhost.